# How to ask for advice on a very specific topic which I don't know in deep?

Tags: support

Correct me if my interpretation is wrong: StackExchange is a collaborative tool for joining effort and spreading knowledge. This is the main purpose of the website.

**I would like to ask for and advice on how to open a question on the following topic.**

I've started reading some stuff about ***Code Generators***. I've been playing with CodeSmith understanding the limits, the pros and cons of this program. But I'm still new.. one question I would like to ask could be: *"which are the pros and limits of CodeSmith compared to the other tools available on the market?"*

I would like to ask not for a comparison, an introduction of this kind of software.

It could appear too broad, so I'm asking here for advice on how to formulate the question. From my point of view the topic is very specific by itself. It's like asking for forensic image analysis tools. How many software of this kind do you know? 1?

The real question I would like to ask is for an introduction about Code Generator software and for artificial intelligence usage and wrapper induction.

http://ajgenesis.codeplex.com/
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=+site:citeseer.ist.psu.edu+%22wrapper+induction%22

Comment: Your "introduction to <subject>" question isn't really within the scope of this site, and not part of the purpose for which this site was created. It's not a matter of wording; I'm afraid your question is going to be off topic here. Hopefully the responses to the question linked above will answer exactly why.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: thanks. I have this doubt. Just to start a reflection (which can also be wrong) I think that even if my question can be completely answered by the one you provided, I'm not sure this concept is logically equivalent to say that the two question are duplicated. The concept of equivalence is really far away http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence, but also.. saying that I can refer to the other question is completely right. Saying that they are duplicated implies something more strong.. I mean, I wonder if this kind of marking is a best practice or not. (not so important